# How does the client get the certificate chain when verifying a TLS connection?

Tags: tls, certificates

When a client creates a TLS connection, he is given a certificate.

To make sure this certificate is authentic the client must look at the certificate chain.

My question is: How does the client get this chain? Is there a special protocol for asking certificates or is he given a complete chain by the host?

Thanks

Comment: This is covered in [our reference question on TLs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) under “Certificates and Authentication”.